# How to change taxonomy term path

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I am using [taxonomy menu](https://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) module but I want to change the taxonomy path from
 taxonomy/term/tid to subject/term title.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Path auto](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module .. Alias taxonomy term paths...

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for
>   various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without
>   requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you
>   to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123.
>   The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which
>   the administrator can change.